Git alias to add files and then show status is showing from parent directory
I work in C# with Unity, and it often touches a lot of files that don't want to commit. My changes that I want to commit are almost always exclusively .cs files. I created a git alias to stage all of my .cs file changes while ignoring everything else. That alias worked, but I realized that after doing the add that I always end up double-checking the results by doing a git status, so I decided to combine the two into a single alias.
addcs = !git add ./\\*.cs && git status
This alias works, however, the git status always shows the results as if I was calling it from the parent branch.
So just doing a git status might show up like this:
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   Scripts/Foo.cs

Calling my alias, which calls a git status within it, shows up like this:
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   ParentDirectory/Scripts/Foo.cs

I tried an alternate alias, thinking that maybe the ./ within my alias might be somehow affecting the git status, but this alias doesn't behave any differently:
addcs = !git add '**/*.cs' && git status
I'm curious if anyone knows why the git status might be behaving this way, and if there's something I can change with my alias to avoid it.

You could add an unconditional refresh of the index between the addition and the status check with git update-index --really-refresh.

Like --refresh, but checks stat information unconditionally, without regard to the "assume unchanged" setting.

Your alias could be rewritten as follows:
git config --local alias.my-add '!sh -c "git add *.cs && git update-index --really-refresh && git status"'


I tried this and for all unstaged changes it lists the file and then says needs update afterward. It doesn't display any git status.

@NicFoster Weird... it worked for me https://i.sstatic.net/19gZ7hx3.png which Git version are you running? Mine is git version 2.45.2.windows.1

@dani-vta, I'm using 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146) on MacOS.

@NicFoster Have you tried updating? I've included a link with a screenshot in my previous comment to show you the behavior. On my version it works as expected.

I'll look into updating, is this functionality fairly new to git?
I checked the docs and it should exist even in 2.38.x versions, which are slightly older than mine: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index/2.38.0

@NicFoster no, it's not new. I cannot understand how it doesn't work for you, but it does for me. I was just trying to analyze the behavior with the same versions and troubleshoot from there.
